# How do i add the signal tabMoved?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I Want to create a map where every tab created is stored in there with his index as a key, the problem is that if I move the position of a tab his index change, so I need to update it only when the tab is moved, I saw in the documentation the signal tabMoved but I can't find how to implement it, usually, in the qt creator I can go to slot and add from there, but i can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to "subscribe" your app to the signal:

```
 void QTabWidget::currentChanged(int index)
```

> This signal is emitted whenever the current page index changes. The parameter is the new current page index position, or -1 if there isn't a new one (for example, if there are no widgets in the QTabWidget)

then you can have an update whenever the user sort/change the tabs order

Comment: yeah i have used this, but this signal also emits when a tab is just selected

Comment: you need to read the index parameter... if that is -1 then you ignore the signal...
just read the doc

Comment: the index is -1 when there are no tabs, can you show me how to connect the signal of 'tabMoved' to the 'tabBar' widget?

Comment: check the position of your tab is changed or not if changed means moved.